# How to classify highly overlapping data after t-sne?

Tags: classification, pca, sample, overlapping, tsne

How to classify highly overlapping data after t-sne?
[plot after t-sne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gn1Q.png)

I have tried t-sne, pca and UMAP. But all are showing the same overlapping sample. Then how to proceed further classification. Is there another way to do it?